# Regex to detect JavaScript Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

I'm trying to write a regex that would detect regex in a javascript file.  I've spent some time and this is what I've come up with:

```
\/.*?\/[a-zA-Z]?
```

This works fine:

```
/^[^0-9][2,3]$/
/^[a-z]+( +[a-z]+){2,}$/g
```

However it fails for something like this:

```
/\/.*?\/[a-zA-Z]?/g
```

Just to clarify my goal,  I'm going to be using this regex to detect regexes in JavaScript code and color code them.

Comment: What happens if I do `/abcd\/abcd/`? Your regex will fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also check whether the `/` is preceeded by a `\` or not to make sure it is not being escaped:

```
(?<!\\)\/.*?(?<!\\)\/[a-zA-Z]?
```

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/wB5gF5)

Comment: will this handle all the cases for a regex string?

Comment: @Pathachiever11, I am fairly confident that it will. You can test them in the demo I posted if you like.

Comment: It's handling the regexs, except it fails to detect JS in 
var replace = string.replace(/\/.*?\/[a-zA-Z]?/g, "ss")

Comment: If you paste the script I wrote in the textbox, the regex does not get highlighted.